# Getting total average between dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `sales` with the following format.

```
sale_id         user_id          sale_date              sale_cost
j847bv-6ggd     bd48ta36-cn5x    2017-01-10 15:43:12    30
vf87x2-15gr     bd48ta36-cn5x    2017-01-05 13:41:16    60
3gfd7f-2cdd     8g4f5ccf-1fet    2017-01-15 14:10:12    100
4bgfd5-12vn     8g4f5ccf-1fet    2017-01-20 19:47:14    20
b58e32-bf87     8g4f5ccf-1fet    2017-01-20 17:35:13    15
bg87db-127g     gr4gg1f4-3gbb    2017-01-20 12:26:15    80
```

How could I get the average amount that a user (`user_d`) spends within the first X amount of days since their first purchase? I don't want an average for every user, but a total average for all.

I know that I can get the average using `select avg(sale_cost)` but I'm unsure how to find out the average for a date period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find average of total for each user within 10 days date range from intial sales date like this:

```
select avg(sale_cost)
from (
    select sum(t.sale_cost) sale_cost
    from your_table t
    join (
        select user_id, min(sale_date) start_date, date_add(min(sale_date), interval 10 day) end_date
        from your_table
        group by user_id
        ) t2 on t.user_id = t2.user_id
        and t.sale_date between t2.start_date and t2.end_date
    group by t.user_id
    ) t;
```

It finds the first sale_date and date 10 days after this for each user. Then joins it with the table to get total for each user within that range and then finally average of the above calculated totals.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/AGECW59568)

If you want to find the average between overall first sale_date (not individual) and 10 days from it, use:

```
select avg(sale_cost)
from (
    select sum(t.sale_cost) sale_cost
    from your_table t
    join (
        select min(sale_date) start_date, date_add(min(sale_date), interval 10 day) end_date
        from your_table
        ) t2 on t.sale_date between t2.start_date and t2.end_date
    group by t.user_id
    ) t;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/VNV95767)

Comment: I don't want ```date1``` and ```date2``` to be hard-coded so to speak. I would ideally like  ```date1``` to be the ```sale_date``` and ```date2``` to be say 10 days from ```date1```

Comment: @Someguywhocodes - Added an another solution. May be that's what you are looking for. Please check?

Comment: I believe the first answer is exactly what I am looking for, the second is also useful though! I seem to have an issue selecting the cost, see [here](http://imgur.com/a/PxmXc). The query looks good so I'm not sure what would cause this, as the column does exist.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes - use `avg(sale_cost)` in your query at very beginning because that what you gave an alias in the subquery. or change the alias from `sale_cost` to `paid_amount`

Answer (score 0):

The between operator comes in handy whenever it comes to checking ranges

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

In this case value1 and value2 will be replaced by your dates using:

```
'2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-01-31 23:59:59'
```

or
    `sale_date AND DATE_ADD(OrderDate,INTERVAL 10 DAY)`

The first way is faster and also the between values are inclusive.

Comment: This works and is a lot more simpler than @GurV answer, is there a difference?

Comment: this answer is bad because it never calculates averages

Comment: I just noticed this! Thanks, will try your answer now.

Comment: Its only the way that code has been written and also i believe in simplifying the presentation of code as much as possible. If suitable kindly mark as answered by clicking on the tick to the left so that others can also benefit from your query. This code only shows the usage of between operator that is needed, not to code to find avg as the user already knew how to calculate average perfectly well

Comment: question is asking to find the total average between two dates and this answer gives just data between two dates.